# Retrieve nested javascript objects in Django view as a dict

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a very simple view that receives an ajax request containing a javascript object. The jquery request looks like this:

```
$.get(URL, {'kwargs': {test: 1}}, function(data){//whatever})
```

The problem is, request.GET now contains a rather strange key and looks like this:

```
{'kwargs[test]': [1]}
```

How can I successfully decode this? As a side note, it is impossible to know the key (test) beforehand

The expected format obtained is a python dict that looks like the one in the request.

I've tried:

```
request.GET.get('kwargs', None)
```

And I'd expect this as a result:

```
{'test': 1}
```

However, I get None, as the real key is 'kwargs[test]'

**EDIT**

I know I could use some kind of regex to accomplish this, but it feels as 'reinventing the wheel', as this use case is not that rare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using JSON when communicating back and forth between the server and client for this type of situation.  JSON is meant to handle these types of nested structures in a uniform manner.

Take a look at using the jQuery $.getJSON functionality,
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

The following is an example of how this structure would look...

Javscript

```
var request_data = {kwargs: {test: 1}};
$.getJSON(URL, {data: JSON.stringify(request_data)}, function(data){//whatever})
```

Django

```
import json
def your_view(request):
    my_json = json.loads(request.GET['data'])
```

Doing this will allow you to parse the request which contains JSON data into a variable of your choice (my_json).  Once you assign your variable with the results of json.loads(), you will now have a python object containing the parsed requested JSON data and you will be able to manipulate your object accordingly.

```
>>> my_json['kwargs']
{u'test': 1}
```

Comment: request.body seems to be an empty bytestring .. I'm using django 1.7

Comment: Do you have any clue on that? I've followed the $.getJSON scheme and I'm getting something in request.GET

Comment: Yup you are right.  `request.body` doesn't get populated for 'GET' requests.  I'll update my answer with more relative information.

Comment: managed to make it work with a mixture of JSON.stringify and $.get.. thanks